# Python can't compile _curses module on Debian Lenny

Tags: python, curses

My Python (2.6) installation on a few servers has been compiled without curses support which I now need, although the servers have libncurses5 installed, Python did not compile the bindings for it so when I "import curses" I get:

```
"ImportError: No module named _curses"
```

my /lib/ dir has the following files and symlinks:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 2010-02-13 05:50 /lib/libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 251K 2008-12-14 22:31 /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 2010-02-13 05:50 /lib/libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 299K 2008-12-14 22:31 /lib/libncursesw.so.5.7
```

and /lib64/ has:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 2010-08-13 12:26 /lib64/libncurses.so -> /lib/libncurses.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 2010-02-13 05:50 /lib64/libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 251K 2008-12-14 22:31 /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 2010-02-13 05:50 /lib64/libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 299K 2008-12-14 22:31 /lib64/libncursesw.so.5.7
```

/usr/lib64 and /usr/lib both have have :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 2010-08-13 12:20 /usr/lib64/libncurses.so -> /lib/libncurses.so.5
```

When I try to 'make' python again, I get back at the end the following warning:

```
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_curses_panel      _tkinter           bsddb185        
bz2                dl                 gdbm            
imageop            readline           sunaudiodev     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Failed to build these modules:
    _curses
```

What do I need to do to recompile Python with curses support? What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which of these actions resolved my problem but one of them did. I installed libncurses5-dev and libreadline5-dev, recompiled python and reinstalled (make / make install). 
Huzza

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's right. Installing `libncurses5-dev` and running `'make'` and `'make install'` on the `python` installation did the trick. I had encountered the error with `_curses` first while trying to install and fire up `bpython` on my custom python installation.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, on CentOS 6.4 64-bit, you need all of these development libraries for compiling Python 2.7.6:

```
yum install -y zlib-devel openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel \
               ncurses-devel readline-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel tk-devel
```

After `yum install` those, run `make` and there are four modules left:

> Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
>
> `bsddb185           dl                 imageop         sunaudiodev`
>
> To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

These are obsolete, according to [this blog post](http://rajaseelan.com/2012/01/28/installing-python-2-dot-7-2-on-centos-5-dot-2/):

> `sunaudiodev` is is for Sun platforms, `dl` for 32bit platforms, `imageop` is deprecated and `bsddb185` is undocumented.